# setup email client to receive emails from mandrillapp

Tags: email, imap, mandrill

I am trying to setup mandrill on my outlook/mac email client. 
I can find the smtp setting in my mandrill account to send emails and it's working perfectly on my outlook/mac also.
But I am not able to understand what settings to do for imap/pop to configure mandrill to receive incoming emails.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mandrill doesn't offer support for imap/pop to receive email. If you want to use Mandrill to manage incoming mail, you'll need to use their inbound processing: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583197-Inbound-Email-Processing-Overview